# Bootstrap Align Checkbox <input> next to Header <h3>

Tags: checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, header, inline

I'm trying to vertically align a bootstrap checkbox & label with a header element. I also want the checkbox & label to be at the far right of the shared grid row.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-inline">
             <h3>Chat Room</h3>

            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" checked> <small>enable presence events</small>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.form-inline h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}

label.checkbox-inline {
    float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zenwoof/7e1f47rz/7/

Results in:

[image]

I'm hoping there's a clean & responsive way to do this, other than a hacky margin/padding fix.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add this css. `label.checkbox-inline {margin-top: 20px;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to Bootstrap so I figured there was some class I neglected to include, but guess not - came down to a hard-coded margin fix which is what I originally did.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,Use same css style:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class=col-md-12">
        <div class="form-inline">
             <h3>Chat Room</h3>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-12" >
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" checked>       <small>enable presence events</small>
            </label>
     </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

/*Note:Please check cairfully hare one div closing tag is missing.chack same mistake in code may be this mistake is only in during posting the problem.*/